# How to Delete group name from group fields in crystal reports

Tags: asp.net

How do you delete a group name in Crystal Reports 2010 with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: What do you mean by a group name ?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to remove a group in the report then Right Click on the Group Header and select Group Expert. Then remove the desired field from the right list.

If you only want to remove the field in the header and footer section of a group then just select the FieldObject (It is a kind on Label) and press delete button.